# document.ready() - post method - nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is it possible to call `document.ready()` in post method in express/node.js?

I am trying to create an app that can show CSV files. For that I am using papaparse. I'd like to know how I call below snippet through the post method.

I just want to show the same uploaded file somewhere in the HTML page.

### post method for upload

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return res.end("Error uploading file.");
        }
        // res.end("File is uploaded");
        res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
    });
});
```

### client-side script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit-file').on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#files').parse({
            config: {
                delimiter: "auto",
                complete: displayHTMLTable,
            },
            before: function(file, inputElem)
            {
                //console.log("Parsing file...", file);
            },
            error: function(err, file)
            {
                //console.log("ERROR:", err, file);
            },
            complete: function()
            {
                //console.log("Done with all files");
            }
        });
    });

    function displayHTMLTable(results){
        var table = "<table class='table table-striped'>";
        var data = results.data;

        for(i=0;i<data.length;i++){
            table+= "<tr>";
            var row = data[i];
            var cells = row.join(",").split(",");

            for(j=0;j<cells.length;j++){
                table+= "<td>";
                table+= cells[j];
                table+= "</th>";
            }
            table+= "</tr>";
        }
        table+= "</table>";
        $("#parsed_csv_list").html(table);
    }
});
```

Comment: No, the document is completely loaded already, but there are several other options you could take. You seem to navigate after a succesfull upload, you could include a reference to the last uploaded file, you could also do the post yourself, using an ajax callback and when completed just show that it successfully uploaded itself, lots of possibilities

Comment: @Icepickle sorry, really am not able to understand..!! 


my question may be really wrong. what am trying to ask is "can we call client side document.ready() from post method?"

Comment: You can't call client side code from the server side.

Comment: @Tomalak do you have any idea about to convert it to sever side from above code.?? if possible means pls share the ways.!!!

Comment: At first you must make a decision about who should render the data, the client or the server. Then stick with it. It looks like your client is prepared to render the data and your function already works there. I don't see why you would want to run that function on the server in the first place?

Comment: @Tomalak first of all am not aware about server side code. i thought it would be better if everything is belong from server side to secure some process. what do think? is it really okay to parse csv file from client side.? if it is not an issue means my problem is solved

Comment: No, that's not necesarily an issue. Whether you let the server do it or the client is a matter of preference and a matter of application architecture. You can decide. Many modern web application are built in such a way that the server sends raw data (e.g. in JSON or CSV format) and the client parses that data and turns it into HTML.

Comment: can you provide any demo example please?